# ASP.NET Get previous page, using MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I need to access the previous page URL but because I am using a MasterPage, I am having difficulty achieving this.

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

This only returns the URL of the current page.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a post here:

- **[Using PreviousPage with Master Pages](http://blogs.mgtechgroup.com/markc/archive/2007/05/03/Using-PreviousPage-with-Master-Pages.aspx) *(c#)***.
- **[Using PreviousPage with Master Pages](http://aspnet101.com/tutorials.aspx?id=66) *(VB)***

**EDIT**

If you are trying to get the last url without any postback, then you will not be able to do this, because HTTP is an stateless protocol.

Comment: I have read & tried that one. It seems to deal with getting data from controls on the previous page, not the previous URL address itself.